# Timeout in Jquery $.post by emulating $.ajax

Tags: jquery

How can we emulate the timeout of `$.ajax` using `$.post`?

Comment: $.post boils down to $.ajax at the end of the day, so it's the same thing? There's no overload for $.post that allows for the timeout parameter though, so you'd need to use $.ajax - potentially this setting could be set in a $.ajaxSetup instead? - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Comment: Why do you need to use `$.post` instead of `$.ajax`? If you must, you can set a global timeout for all requests using [`$.ajaxSetup({'timeout': ...})`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.POST` is a preset version of `$.ajax`, so few parameter are already set.

> As a matter of fact, a `$.post` is equal to
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>   type: 'POST',
>   url: url,
>   data: data,
>   success: success,
>   dataType: dataType
> });
> ```

But, you can create your own post function to send the request through `$.ajax` at last.

Here is a custom POST plugin I just coded.

```
(function( $ ){
  $.myPOST = function( url, data, success, timeout ) {      
    var settings = {
      type : "POST", //predefine request type to POST
      'url'  : url,
      'data' : data,
      'success' : success,
      'timeout' : timeout
    };
    $.ajax(settings)
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Now the custom POST function is ready

Usage:

```
$.myPOST(
    "test.php", 
    { 
      'data' : 'value'
    }, 
    function(data) { },
    5000 // this is the timeout   
);
```

### Enjoy :)

Comment: Will this not spawn multiple calls to the script and cause a new dataset to be generated with each call?